# Differents routes on an HTTP handler with Deno

Tags: typescript, deno

Im trying to do a REST API with the deno http lib, the problem arrive when I "declare" routes comparing the req.url property
Here is the TypeScript code:

```
async function handler(req: Request): Promise<Response> {
    if (req.url === "/") {
        return new Response(`Ruta visitada ${req.url}`)
    }
    if (req.url === "/about") {
        return new Response(`Ruta visitada ${req.url}`)
    }
}
```

(Getting the function type `Promise<Response>` underlined as a error)

But I get the next error:

Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.

So how can separe the routes if the function must return directly a response?

Comment: What do you want the API to return if something other than `/` or `/about` is requested?

Comment: e.g. You can add a final `return` statement to create and return a 404 (Not Found) `Response`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll address one part of your question at a time, starting with the types used:

---

### Types

Because you mentioned "the deno http lib" (presumably you mean the collection of modules at `https://deno.land/std/http`), the request handler function you've shown is being passed as the first argument to the [`serve`](https://deno.land/std@0.150.0/http/server.ts?code#L572) function export from [`https://deno.land/std@0.150.0/http/server.ts`](https://deno.land/std@0.150.0/http/server.ts). Its [type](https://doc.deno.land/https://deno.land/std@0.150.0/http/server.ts/%7E/serve) signature looks like this:

```ts
async function serve(handler: Handler, options?: ServeInit): Promise<void>;
```

The [type](https://doc.deno.land/https://deno.land/std@0.150.0/http/server.ts/%7E/Handler) signature of that [`Handler`](https://deno.land/std@0.150.0/http/server.ts?code#L35) function looks like this:

```ts
type Handler = (request: Request, connInfo: ConnInfo) => Response | Promise<Response>;
```

> Here's a potentially helpful tip: the `Handler` type is exported from the `server.ts` module, so you can just import it and use it as a [type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) for a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function), avoiding the need to write out the whole function signature type again in a [declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function):
>
> ```ts
> import { type Handler } from "https://deno.land/std@0.150.0/http/server.ts";
>
> const handler: Handler = async (req) => {
>   // ...
> };
> ```

The [`Request`](https://doc.deno.land/deno/stable/%7E/Request) type is an instance of the [`Request` class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request) from the [fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#request-class).

Now, with that covered, I'll address the different concerns of your question:

---

### Understanding the Request URL

> the req.url property

The code you've shown implies that you think the value at this property is the URL string without the [`origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/origin) portion (or, in other words, a concatenation of the [pathname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/pathname) and [query string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/search)).

> I don't want to make any assumptions, but perhaps you are used to the syntax `req.url` often seen in Node.js code, which refers to [`http.IncomingMessage#url`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#messageurl) when used in the request listener argument passed to [`http.createServer`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#httpcreateserveroptions-requestlistener). Example:
>
> ```js
> http.createServer((req, res) => {
>   req.url; // <--- `req` is actually "IncomingMessage"
>   // ...
> });
> ```

In Deno: because the `req` parameter is a class instance described above in the types section of this answer, `req.url` is the **full** URL string (including the [`origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/origin)). To get a [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) object that you can use to branch your program logic (this is called routing), you can use the [`URL` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) like this:

```ts
const url = new URL(req.url);
```

Then, use the properties of that object to make decisions. For example, if you want to send one kind of response when the [pathname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/pathname) is `"/about"`, you can use this:

```ts
const url = new URL(req.url);

if (url.pathname === "/about") {
  // Send a response here...
}
```

This leads to your error and main question(s):

---

### Basic routing logic based on URL pathname

> (Getting the function type `Promise<Response>` underlined as a error)
>
> But I get the next error:
>
> Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.
>
> So how can separe the routes if the function must return directly a response?

This is at the core of every web framework, and — just like there are many web frameworks — there are many approaches with varying levels of complexity. I'll show a simple approach based on the code sample in your question:

I'll create an example TypeScript module, and I'll name it based on the ID of this Stack Overflow question: `so-73171658.ts`. Here is the content of the module:

```ts
import {
  type Handler,
  serve,
} from "https://deno.land/std@0.150.0/http/server.ts";

const handler: Handler = (req) => {
  const url = new URL(req.url);

  if (url.pathname === "/") {
    return new Response(`Ruta visitada ${req.url}`);
  }
  if (url.pathname === "/about") {
    return new Response(`Ruta visitada ${req.url}`);
  }
  return new Response("Not found", { status: 404 });
};

await serve(handler);
```

Notice that, after the two conditional statements, I added a final `return` statement:

```ts
return new Response("Not found", { status: 404 });
```

This is what is returned in the case that a request doesn't match either of the pathnames in the conditional statements.

This change alone will fix the error you received.

Let's test it by running the server:

```
% deno run --allow-net so-73171658.ts
Listening on http://localhost:8000/
```

> Note that, [by default](https://deno.land/std@0.150.0/http/server.ts?code#L531), the `serve` function listens on the hostname `"0.0.0.0"` and the port `8000`

Now that the server is running, let's send a few test requests and read the response body as text. In a separate terminal shell (you can just open a new tab/window in your terminal):

First, let's send a request to the root path `"/"`:

```
% deno eval --print "await (await fetch('http://localhost:8000/')).text()"
Ruta visitada http://localhost:8000/
```

As expected, we get the value of `request.url`. Next, let's send a request to the path `"/about"`:

```
% deno eval --print "await (await fetch('http://localhost:8000/about')).text()"
Ruta visitada http://localhost:8000/about
```

Again (as expected) we get the value of `request.url`. Now, let's send a request to the path `"/another-path"`:

```
% deno eval --print "await (await fetch('http://localhost:8000/another-path')).text()"
Not found
```

This time we get `"Not found"`. This is because there's no conditional statement for the `"/another-path"` pathname, so the final `return` statement is used. The same will happen for all other paths which aren't explicitly handled.

Let's switch back to the terminal shell (tab/window) where the server is running and stop it using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>.

---

### Conclusion

There's **a lot more** involved in routing that I didn't cover in this answer, and is out of scope of the question that you asked. Even *just* in regard to forming correct responses:

- sending the correct [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) (e.g. setting the correct [`content-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header)
- setting a correct/meaningful [status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)
- etc.

You'll need to consult the many sources of available documentation on the internet in order to ensure that your API follows the established standards. ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview) is a great one — I've cited it many times in this answer.)

But you don't have to re-implement everything yourself: there are existing Deno web frameworks to help you. Here are a couple:

- [Oak](https://deno.land/x/oak) - "A middleware framework for Deno's native HTTP server, [Deno Deploy](https://deno.com/deploy) and Node.js 16.5 and later. It also includes a middleware router."
- [Sift](https://deno.land/x/sift) - "Sift is a routing and utility library for Deno and [Deno Deploy](https://deno.com/deploy)."

I hope this answer helps you understand some of the basics!

Comment: wow, I can see that I was very confused with all, now I understand it much better, thank u :) @jsejcksn

Comment: @Raxabi No problem; glad you’re learning and feeling more confident. Just curious for my own learning: was my hunch about the Node.js stuff accurate, or was the confusion about `req.url` caused by something else?

Comment: You was right with that, expecially because I use express to build mern apps very much and I want to try deno, but I didn't know that deno works more "natively" compared with node. @jsejcksn